# Dynamically create multiple divs and assign different css property for each using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am stuck with an issue where I am not able to create multiple divs with different css attributes using a loop. It will be really helpful if someone guide me.

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        ....
        ....
        ....
            $(".container").append('<div class="event" ><a>Sample text</a></div>');
            $(".event").css("top",start+"px");
            $(".event").css("width","94%");
            $(".event").css("height",heightVal+"px");

    }
```

I am only getting one div created inside my container. I think the issue is with the way I am appending my child divs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the array.length bigger than 1?

Comment: @arop yes, it is of length 4.

Comment: your problem is creating the new elements or styling them??

Comment: I believe the append is correct, I think what is happening is that all of the divs are in the same place because of the css. Try using a different id for each div appended

Comment: @JVLobo  The problem is that divs are getting created but they are getting replaced by the next one. So finally I am left with one div for the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: @arop I understood your point but I am not able to create id's dynamically and assign css property for each one of them. Can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: I see... I posted a solution that I think should solve your issue.

Comment: @jstandshigh did you see my solution that uses an object for multiple css??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".container").append('<div class="event" ><a>Sample text</a></div>');
$(".event").css("top",start+"px");
$(".event").css("width","94%");
$(".event").css("height",heightVal+"px");
```

You need to contextualize your lookups.  You are creating an event in the container, but then you are selecting every event to change it's css.  Change the logic to possibly...

```
var $event = $('<div class="event" ><a>Sample text</a></div>');
$(".container").append($event);
$event.css("top",start+"px");
$event.css("width","94%");
$event.css("height",heightVal+"px");
```

Comment: @jstandshigh did you see my solution that uses an object for multiple css??

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem comes because you're dynamically creating the elements, and them trying to apply some styles through the class selector, and this doesn't work.

I'd do in this way:

```
var new_element = $('<div class="event" ><a>Sample text</a></div>');
$(".container").append(new_element);
$(new_element).css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a container and append your divs in there. Also, it's better to use an object for multiple styles (CSS). Take a look at my solution. Hope it helps :).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  $('#container').append('<div class="event" ><a>Sample text</a></div>').css({
    "width":"94%",
    "color":"blue"
     });
    }

  $(".event:eq(2)").css({
    "background": "red" ,
    "color":"green",
    "width":"300px"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @jstandshigh can you at least vote my answer up? Thanks

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way to change the div width if it is overlapping with another div in the loop

Comment: @jstandshigh yes everything is possible, but if you want to change the div's width you must target it by its position.

Comment: @jstandshigh I just updated my answer so you can see the it's possible to change a div's width. Hope it helps!

Comment: @basically what I'm doing is target the 3 div and changing its width.